# MemoryMappedFiles on mono

Tags: c#, mono, fedora

I’ve used memory mapped files in windows and visual studio successfully, but,I’m trying to migrate a project  to mono and fedora 17 , my code is as simple as this:

```
Var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(@"/home/xxx/xxx/filename", 1024*1024);
```

Unlike visual studio, in the filename you have to put an existing file. Otherwise, you get a File NofoundException, I was getting the “Capacity exception” but calling the method with the exact file size I now getting a new exception:

```
Mono.Unix.UnixIOException: File exists [EEXIST].
at Mono.Unix.UnixMarshal.ThrowExceptionForLastError () [0x00000]
    in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixMarshal.cs:456
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMapImpl.Open (System.String path, FileMode mode, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x0006b]
    in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs:133
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00055]
    in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs:475
at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew (System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileSecurity memoryMappedFileSecurity, HandleInheritability handleInheritability) [0x00000]
    in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs:525
at Unixtest.MainClass.Inicialize () [0x00009] 
    in /home/xxx/xxx/Unixtest/Main.cs:50 }
```

I’m stuck here, any ideas?

Comment: `CreateNew` creates a new file and throws an exception if the file already exists. `UnixIOException: File exists` tells you that the file already exists. Solution: don't use `CreateNew`.

Comment: How do you expect us from just an exception message? The problem exists within UnixMarshal.cs on line 456. We need the all methods that communicate with the method this line is connected to.  At the basic level the file already exists, check if it exists, and if it does resolve the conflict.

Comment: Very good mono, if the file doesn’t exists throws a File Not Found Exception, and if exists throws a File Exist Exception. CreateOrOpen is the one

Comment: I don't know why, but Mono's implementation is using `open()`, not `mmap()`.  There are also some comments in the code which indicate that the code is incomplete and not 100% compatible with Microsoft.